# Simulate excel macro on mobile

Tags: iphone

I have an excel with 150 rows of hyperlinks. I've written a macro that clicks through all the links. I want to do the same on my mobile phone but excel on mobile doesn't allow macros. Is there an alternative to this? My objective is to automatically click through 150 hyperlinks. Please and thank you.

I haven't tried anything else